# Альтернативы Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли альтернативы Microsoft SQL Management Studio с расширенными возможностями работы с кодом?

Ну например, хотелось бы как в Visual Studio видя в коде какую-то юзерскую процедуру, прыгнуть на ее реализацию.

В стандартной Microsoft SQL Management Studio такой штуки не нашел, а ручками аждый раз искать пользовательские функции и открывать просмотр не удобно...

Comment: Речь как я понимаю именно про MSSQL в качестве БД?

Comment: [dbForge Studio](https://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/sql/studio/). Но вопрос не соответствует тематике SO.

Comment: Посмотрите на плагины к SSMS. Список от одного из хабрапользователей с краткими описаниями: https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/blob/master/SSMS/SSMS_Addins.md Даже после установки минимума - SSMSBoost, SQL Prompt, HauntDog, Redgate SQL Search желание смотреть на dbForge и 0xDBE угасает довольно быстро

Answer (score 5):

Добрый день.

Полный список инструментов и утилит для SQL Server найдете здесь: https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit/tree/master/Utilities

Сейчас работаю над добавлением классификации для всех инструментов.

Конкретно вас из списка могут заинтересовать следующие менеджеры для работы с базой данных (в порядке моего предпочтения и с указанием поддержки других баз данных и цены):

- **dbForge Studio for SQL Server**, только SQL Server, Бесплатно или от $200
- **DataGrip**, не только SQL Server, $89
- **DBeaver**, не только SQL Server, Open Source
- **HeidiSQL**, не только SQL Server, Open Source
- **EMS SQL Manager for SQL Server**, только SQL Server, Freeware или от $189
- **Toad for SQL Server**, только SQL Server, $? (необходимо запрашивать цену у продажников)

Comment: топикастер ищет не список утилит. он ищет конкретную утилиту с конкретным функционалом навигации по коду. все менеджеры из списка поддерживают прямую навигацию (go to definition, вроде F12 в visual studio)?

Comment: DbForge есть решения и для других баз данных, да и вроде как для *пощупать* есть *бесплатная* версия

Comment: Bald, спасибо, действительно есть (просто она довольно таки сильно урезана) - поправил.  PashaPash, вспомнил почему стараюсь избегать рускоязычных ресурсов - я думаю автору виднее что именно он ищет и как бы заголовок вопроса однозначен.

Answer (score 3):

Решается плагинами, например [SQL Promt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) обеспечивает удобную навигацию, подсказки и форматирование, правда платный.